# Synchronizing value change in Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a ViewModel in android and I am trying to validate whether the person has entered his name and age before moving on to the next page.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
fun onContinueClick() {
  val navigateNextPage: (Int) -> Unit = lambda@{ validation ->
    if (validation < 2)
      return@lambda

    nextPageUseCase().onEach {
      _navigationNotify.value = it // Moving on to the next page
    }
  }

  viewModelScope.launch {
    var valid = 0
    getName().collect { name ->
      if (name != null) navigateNextPage(++valid)
    }
    getAge().collect { age ->
      if (age != null) navigateNextPage(++valid)
    }
  }
}
```

Although this is working as expected, is it efficient to perform this operation? I think that if both the `++valid` happen at the same time, I wouldn't be able to go to the next page.
I want to know how to synchronize the code to avoid that situation.

Comment: How would they happen at the same time, though? You have two synchronous `collect` operations. I don't see any concurrency there.

Comment: `collect` is a synchronous function? I believe I may have confused myself. Since flows use coroutines for it's operations, I assumed collect is asynchronous.

Comment: Coroutines don't imply asynchrony at all, execution within a coroutine's happens sequentially. `collect` is just another suspendable function.